# Problem with org-mode code structure "#+begin_src lisp" in spacemacs

Tags: lisp, org-mode, spacemacs

when I'm writting a code in lisp in a org-mode file. I started a block

```
      #+begin_src lisp
      #+end_src
```

When I write the fist line no problem, functions names highlight correctly.

```
      #+begin_src lisp
      (defun myappend (L1 L2)
(cond

          
      #+end_src
```

but when I press enter on the second line, it starts to be weird.

```
      #+begin_src lisp
        (d    efun myappend (L1 L2)
(c        ond

                        
    
      #+end_src
```

Indentation is inserted in the code. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this an org buffer? Those look like org tags marking the beginning and end of the source.

Comment: yes it is, sorry I just specified with the tags

Comment: Try using `M-x org-edit-special` (bound to `C-c '` by default) to write the code in the source block. When you're done, do `C-c '` again to return to the org file.

Comment: Thank you, that's it, I think I didn't know that the code must be written separatly, sorry. Sorry also Silvio if I miss understood your question.